# Is there any integration or an option to display the terraform plan output on the GitHub console?

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, github-actions, github-api, terraform-cloud

For every PR we create, terraform cloud triggers the plan as a pre-commit. Now we are looking for an option if we can capture the output of plan and have it displayed on the GitHub Console somehow, instead of navigating through different options like terraform cloud or Jenkins Console Output.

I tried reading about GitHub Actions, Perhaps we do not need this solution right now. Because it kinda replaces Jenkins pipeline of our infrastructure deployment, which we do not want. Any recommendations or solutions here would be appreciated?